# How can I test a model on longer sequences that it is trained on

Tags: cnn, lstm, image-classification

I am trying to train a model on ECGs. Unfortunately, I do not have enough data for 30s ecgs but I have sufficient data for 10s ecgs. I have trained a CNN model and performs really well on the 10s data.
Is there a way to use the features extracted on the 10s ECGs to classify the 30s ecgs?

I was thinking that a cnn-lstm model would work by spliting the 30s data to 10s data, extracting the features and then training a LSTM however it hasnt and I am not sure why.

PS: I have converted the ecgs to RGB images in the time-frequency domain

Thank you